# php code logic for transferring data from one page to another

Tags: php, mysql

i made a (php) form, and used php session and post to transfer the form data to another page, which gives the user an option to have a look at the data and if wrong he shall move to the main form..

now here is what i did

on page1 i made a main form say form1, when user clicks on submit, i saved the data to DB and added that id to a session, and sent that session to next page using the same id 
on next page i called from db matching the same id and displayed data accordingly..

now i displayed the data (on the second page) inside a div styled with css, the logic for this second page is giving the user the choice if the data is wrong he can edit, and bottom of this div i added a button with code

```
<a href="#" class="button3">Edit</a>
```

now my question is this, what shall be next? my target is, if user clicks on this edit button he shall be taken to main form (i.e. page1, form1) and there he shall has the option of editing the data in the same id. How can i achieve this friends?

Also i used

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

on top of both the pages...

Answer (score 2):

Just change your code on the form1 page to; load the data from the database if the id of the record is set in your session variable.

Then if the user decides the data is wrong he just gets sent back to form1 and has the possibility to make changes.

Use something similar to: `value="<?php echo $data['name']"` in your input fields.

Then check for the id and load the data:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['record_id'])) {
    // Do a query with `where id = record_id
    // Fetch the data in the $data variable
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you dont want use GET then use SESSION.

in file.php  set

```
     $_SESSION['your_id'] = $theid ;
```

and in your edit.php retrieve it like that

```
   $id = $_SESSION['your_id']  ;
```

of course you must session_start in both files.

Comment: i do not want to use get, becuase get displays value in the url and suppose i send just id to next page and it is displayed in url, if a user change the id in url to some other number he maybe able to pull data relavant to that id, does he not?

Comment: Instead of creating a new page, with all the styling and HTML repeated, how about linking to the page1 with the GET parameter passed. In page1, check if GET is set, it is integer etc and prefill the form, else show a blank form. It will lead to page2 with option to go back to edit or proceed further.

Comment: @echo_Me i have done the same.. now i want to ask, when user is on second page, and clicks on edit button, then where shall i send him again? 

here is the code of edit button <a href="#" class="button3">Edit</a>

Comment: you will send him to same page with if(isset($_POST['edit'])){then do your code}. of course you will use a form not just <a> link

Comment: means on the second page i shall again use the form??

Comment: first page you dont have to use form if you just link to that page , but in second page use form to get your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have all the data in your session you can simply link back to the first page. All you have to do is set all of your fields on the first page to pre-fill with the session data as long as it `isset`. This way, when you go back the forms will auto fill with the data the user has already entered and they can simply change what is needed.